# Understanding working of sed in bash

Tags: sed

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "the first application of sed"
sed -e 's/^\([0-9]\{3\}\)/(\1)/' s.txt
echo "the second application of sed"
sed -e 's/^\([0-9]\{3\}\)/(\1\+\1)/' s.txt
echo "see the original file"
cat s.txt

the first application of sed
(905)-123-3456
(905)-124-3456
(905)-125-3456
(905)-126-3456
(905)-127-3456
the second application of sed
(905+905)-123-3456
(905+905)-124-3456
(905+905)-125-3456
(905+905)-126-3456
(905+905)-127-3456
see the original file
905-123-3456
905-124-3456
905-125-3456
905-126-3456
905-127-3456
```

I'm just starting out in shell programming and for the last 2 hours I'm stuck with this code. I know the basic usage of sed but I cannot figure out what the line

```
sed -e 's/^\([0-9]\{3\}\)/(\1)/' s.txt
```

does. I know -e is expression, s is substitute. ^ indicates beginning of line but the part after that is confusing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, it is manual-bashing exercise.

- `\(` marks the start of a capture, up to the balanced `\)` — they can be nested, though these ones don't.
- `\{` marks the start of a repeat specification up to the following `\}` — they cannot be nested.  In this case, you have `\{3\}` so this repeats the previous item, `[0-9]`, three times.
- The `\1` in the replacement refers the material captured by the first `\(` in the search pattern.

Hence:

```
s/^\([0-9]\{3\}\)/(\1)/
```

wraps the three digits at the start of the line in parentheses — as shown in your output.  Because it is anchored, it happens just once.  If a line doesn't start with three digits, nothing happens to that line as a result of this command.

The second example is only marginally different.  It takes the sequence of three digits at the start of the line and replaces it with that sequence, a `+` mark, and the sequence again, all wrapped in parentheses — as shown in your output.

There are relatively few metacharacters in the replacement part of a `s///` command; there are a lot of metacharacters in the search part.  Further, there are different dialects in the search part — some variants of `sed` support 'extended regular expressions' instead of 'basic regular expressions' (which is what your example uses); others support Perl-like expressions (not quite the full PCRE — Perl Compatible Regular Expressions — as far as I know, but some notations from PCRE).  For that, you need to read the manual for the `sed` you're using.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now! Also, is there a way I can do this without wrapping the digits in parentheses in my output?

Comment: nvm, I figures it out.

Comment: As you will have figured out, don't include the parentheses in the replacement part of the `s///` command.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this down:

```
sed -e 's/^\([0-9]\{3\}\)/(\1)/' s.txt
```

The nomenclature of sed's substitute is like this:

```
s/search/replace/options
```

In your case, `search` part is `^\([0-9]\{3\}\)`. Parenthesis and curly brackets can have special meaning and they are escaped by a `\`. If we remove them for understanding purposes, this is how it will look:

```
^([0-9]{3})
```

It means - the line should start with a number between 0 and 9 and it should be repeated 3 times. So basically, it's a 3 digit number (e.g. 123, 543 etc.).

The parenthesis () groups the 3 digit number, which can be referred to as the first group.

The replace part of it is `(\1)`. That means, the group we captured in search is regurgitated.

Comment: It's regurgitated wrapped in parentheses; the `(` and `)` in the replacement are not metacharacters but simply characters that appear where the replacement text appears.